# Error running pod install || Error launching application on iPhone

Tags: ios, swift

when I run app in android studio it doesn't seems to display on the phone simulator and the error is ;

```
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 14 Pro in debug mode...
Running pod install...
CocoaPods' output:
↳


Error output from CocoaPods:
↳

    [!] Automatically assigning platform `iOS` with version `16.1` on target `Runner` because no platform was specified. Please specify a platform for this target in your Podfile. See `https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html#platform`.

Error running pod install
Error launching application on iPhone 14 Pro.
```

I have deleted the pod file and tried to install the pod again but still same old issue. Everything I try doesn't work.

Comment: This indeed looks like an issue with CocoaPods. I would recommend the following:

 - Delete your Podfile.lock file
 - Run pod repo update to ensure you have the latest specs
 - Re-run pod install

This should reinstall your pods and hopefully resolve the issue. If not, I would also ensure that your Podfile has a platform line, like this:

platform :ios, '16.1'

Comment: I did that but it gives the error

Comment: you need to share your podfile as it clearly states there is not platform mentioned there

Comment: # Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '16.1'

# CocoaPods analytics sends network stats synchronously affecting flutter build latency.
ENV['COCOAPODS_DISABLE_STATS'] = 'true'

project 'Runner', {
  'Debug' => :debug,
  'Profile' => :release,
  'Release' => :release,